# Rspec no route matches, checking for flash message in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I need to test that a flash message comes up when a specific exception is raised. I am getting a no route matches error and have looked through the other topics with "Rspec Controller test, No Routes matches" and am still not sure what is wrong. This is my first time writing an rspec test. Commented out lines are various other attempts to get test to pass.

audit/businesses_controller.rb:

```
class Audit::BusinessesController < ApplicationController    
# PUT /audit/businesses/:id
def update
  remove_deleted_account_numbers_in(params)
  @business = @jurisdiction.businesses.find(params[:id])
  @business.changed_by = current_user

if @business.update_attributes(audit_business_params)
  success_message('update')

else
  @business.initialize_accounts
  @business = @business
  render :edit, alert: t('flash.save_failed')
end 
rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
  if e.message.include? "foreign key constraint"
    @business = @jurisdiction.businesses.find(params[:id])
    @business.initialize_accounts
    @business = @business
  render :edit, alert: "This account number is in use and cannot be    deleted"
  else
    raise e
  end
end
```

business_controller_spec.rb:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Audit::BusinessesController do

describe "handling ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid" do
 before {delete, url = 'audit/jurisdictions/:jurisdiction_id/businesses/:id(.:format)'} 
 it "should rescue with a flash message" do
#     /audit/jurisdictions/:jurisdiction_id/businesses/:id(.:format) 
#      delete, businesses_id: '80776', jurisdiction_id: '795', format: 'html', id: "234769"  
   expect(page).to have_content("This account number is in use and cannot be deleted")
 end
 end
end
```

rake routes:

```
audit_businesses GET       
/audit/jurisdictions/:jurisdiction_id/businesses(.:format)                                                           

audit/businesses#
POST    /audit/jurisdictions/:jurisdiction_id/businesses(.:format)                                                           

audit/businesses#create
new_audit_business GET     
/audit/jurisdictions/:jurisdiction_id/businesses/new(.:format)                                                        

audit/businesses#new
  edit_audit_business GET    

/audit/jurisdictions/:jurisdiction_id/businesses/:id/edit(.:format)                                                    
audit/businesses#edit
audit_business 
GET    /audit/jurisdictions/:jurisdiction_id/businesses/:id(.:format)                                                         
audit/businesses#show
PUT    /audit/jurisdictions/:jurisdiction_id/businesses/:id(.:format)                                                       audit/businesses#update
DELETE /audit/jurisdictions/:jurisdiction_id/businesses/:id(.:format)                                                       audit/businesses#destroy
```

Error Message:

```
Failure/Error: before { delete audit_business_path(:jurisdiction_id, :id, :format) }
ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"audit/businesses", :action=>"/audit/jurisdictions/jurisdiction_id/businesses/id.format"}
 # ./spec/controllers/businesses_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

When I change the spec to:

```
describe Audit::BusinessesController do

 describe "handling ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid" do
   it "should rescue with a flash message" do
     put :update, :jurisdiction_id => 1, :id => 1, :format => html
     expect(controller).to set_flash[:alert].to(/This account number is in use and cannot be deleted/).now
```

The error is:

```
Failure/Error: put :update, :jurisdiction_id => 1, :id => 1, :format => html
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `can_update?' for nil:NilClass
```

routes.rb:

```
  namespace :audit do
root to: 'site#home'

resources :labels,        only: ['index', 'destroy'] do
  post 'delete_queue', on: :collection
  get 'print',         on: :collection
  get 'print_view',    on: :collection
  get 'mark_printed',  on: :collection
  get 'users',         on: :collection
end
resources :auditor_goals
resources :contracts
resource  :contract_work, only: %w[show update], controller: 'contract_work'
resources :manpower

resource :county_budgets, only: :update do
  get 'search'
end

get  'intro_letter_search' => 'files#intro_letter_search'
put  'intro_letter_update' => 'files#intro_letter_update'
get  'search'           => 'files#search'
get  'calendar'         => 'files#calendar'
get  'autocomplete'     => 'files#autocomplete'
get  'direct'           => 'files#direct'

get  'size_code_select' => 'businesses#size_code_select'

scope '/jurisdictions/:jurisdiction_id' do
  resources :businesses, controller: 'businesses'
  resources :files,      controller: 'files' do 
    get 'print',         on: :member
  end
    # get 'page/:page', action: :index, on: :collection
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for rspec test instead write

expect(page).to have_content("flash message")

where "flash message" is the actual message of the error or exception you're trying to make pass. Eg for, flash[:notice] = "An error occurred", you would put have_content("An error occurred")

Hope that helps?!

Justin

Comment: So in your case it would be expect(page).to have_content("This account number is in use and cannot be deleted")

Comment: That makes more sense for what to expect. However, still getting that RoutingError.

Comment: Hmm, try replacing the delete audit_business_path(etc) in your test with delete, url: {' audit/jurisdictions/:jurisdiction_id/businesses/:id(.:format)' } and see if it recognises the route?

Comment: Progress!I am getting a new error: Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content("This account number is in use and cannot be deleted")
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find xpath "/html"
Hopefully there will be a simple fix for this once I search. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! Let me know how you get on with it! Also I don't suppose you'd mind throwing a vote y way would you?? Ha thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@TzokinB - I believe "Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath "/html" typically means the test set is now looking for a view. Have you associated a view for to action in your controller?